# sudo npm install --global fails without error message on Linux

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm attempting to install yarn using npm, as is recommended by the yarn project itself. At first I tried running `npm install --global yarn`, which failed due to inadequate permissions, so I tried again with `sudo npm install --global  yarn`.

But that gave me the following result:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   '--global',
npm verb cli   'yarn' ]
npm info using npm@6.14.4
npm info using node@v10.19.0
npm verb npm-session 92d2a6de56a6da3f
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn 194ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 249ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 2ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 3ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 7ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 7ms
npm verb correctMkdir /root/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-3a08f0df5026584d.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm timing action:extract Completed in 75ms
npm info lifecycle yarn@1.22.10~preuninstall: yarn@1.22.10
npm info lifecycle yarn@1.22.10~uninstall: yarn@1.22.10
npm verb unbuild rmStuff yarn@1.22.10 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm info lifecycle yarn@1.22.10~postuninstall: yarn@1.22.10
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 6ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 6ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 2ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 5ms
npm info lifecycle yarn@1.22.10~preinstall: yarn@1.22.10

> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
```

The command exits with exit code 1. The same result occurs in an `sudo -i` shell. I added the `--verbose` flag to try to see what's going on, but there's still no discernible error message. And sure enough, yarn isn't installed when I try to run it or use `which` on it. I also checked `~/.npm/_logs` and there are no logs for this error, only logs for the permission errors I encountered when I tried to run it without `sudo`. Why is this failing?

Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Edit:

I was able to find the relevant log file in `/root/.npm/_logs`. It showed this as the error message:

```
error Cannot find module './get-uid-gid.js'
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: `sudo npm install --global install yarn` : Is that really what you typed? Or a mistake?

Comment: With sudo, the install logs might be in /root/.npm, or somewhere in /var/log.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman that was a mistake

Comment: For Ubuntu I found that it is better to install node using nvm to limit changes to just your linux account: https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/

Comment: you should _never_ need `sudo` with npm. If you do, something went  terribly wrong. Global installs with `-g` are still "local" to your user account and never need root access.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when I try to install without it, I get flooded with permission errors. This is a brand new Linux installation with a brand new node installation, so I can’t imagine what could have been screwed up.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Specifically, it throws permission errors when it tries to access `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn`.

Comment: What you want to know is why `npm install -g yarn` doesn't work, so let's start there: what's the actual log you get, without `sudo`, because I'm willing to bet if we google/SO-search for that error, you'll find exactly what's wrong with your npm installation. And even before we do that: how did you install Node? Did you use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)? If not, let's start there: purge Node from your install, and use nvm to install it instead. (and then remember to add the [export statement](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) to your .bash_profile)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did install it using `apt`, not realizing that was the wrong thing to do. I just purged it and tried installing nvm, but apparently nvm doesn't really support fish, the shell I use. I have to dip into bash to use nvm, npm, or yarn, but it does all work now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://eshlox.net/2019/01/27/how-to-use-nvm-with-fish-shell

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that might help thoso struggling with the issue is:

- Maybe you set the config globally using `sudo` (in case of linux).
- Check all possible locations of npmrc/.npmrc file, maybe one of them has the wrong configuration line. In my case was `cafile=` (empty after the equal sign), probably causing npm to interpret that as a directory as we can see from the error message.
- Check the /root/.npmrc file. I accidentally set the `cafile=` via `sudo config set ca` (theory).